# Dropping rows and finding the average of a speific column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to remove specific rows from the dataset and find the average of a specific column after the rows are removed without changing the original dataset

```
import pandas as PD
import NumPy as np
df = PD.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\nba.CSV")
NBA = PD.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\nba.CSV")
NBA.drop([25,72,63],axis=0)

I NEED TO FIND THE AVERAGE OF A SPECIFIC COLUMN LIKE "AGE" 

HOWEVER THIS ISNT WORKING: Nba.drop([25,72,63],axis=0),['Age'].mean() 
NEITHER IS THE QUERY COMMAND OR THE. LOC COMMAND
```

Comment: Removed the ALL CAPS - taken as SHOUTING.

Comment: Can you write the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this? I think there was a typo in your code

```
Nba.drop([25,72,63],axis=0)['Age'].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code to drop the rows is correct.

```
NBA_clean = NBA.drop([25,72,63],axis=0)
```

will give you a new dataframe with some rows removed.

To find the average of a specific column, you can use index notation, which will return a series containing that specific row:

```
NBA_Age = NBA_clean["Age"]
```

Finally, to return the mean, you simply call the `mean()` method with:

```
NBA_mean_age = NBA_Age.mean()
```

It is not clear what the specific mistake in your code is, but I will present two possibilities:

1. You are not saving the result of `NBA.drop([25,72,63],axis=0)` into a variable. This operation is not done in place, if you want to do it in place you must use the `inplace=True` argument for `NBA.drop([25,72,63], axis=0, inplace=True)`.
2. There is an unnecessary comma in `Nba.drop([25,72,63],axis=0),['Age'].mean()`. Remove this to get the correct syntax `Nba.drop([25,72,63],axis=0)['Age'].mean()`. I suspect the error message obtained when running this code would have hinted at the unnecessary comma.